# how to convert Date datatype to mm/dd/yyyy format in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I have a procedure which takes `Start_date` and `End_Date` as input parameters. These parameters are of Date datatype.My query is as follows:

`select count(1) from table_name where inspection_date between start_date and end_date;`

when I provide values the input parameters as:
start_date: 1/1/1800 or 1/1/2000 the query take the start date as 1-jan-00 as result of which I am not getting  correct result.

I also tried to convert it into mm/dd/yyyy format using `to_date(to_char(start_date,'mm/dd/yyyy),'mm/dd/yyyy')` and stored in a variable of type `timestamp(6)` but still its not giving correct result .

Please let me know how to perform this operation.

Comment: The string "of no use" is not an error message in Oracle.

Comment: The parameters to the procedure are of type `date`. Are you passing strings in to the procedure or are you passing dates? What does it mean to "take the start date as 1-jan-00"?

Comment: i am passing dates. what i mean to say is that i want year in yyyy format but it is taking year as yy format

Answer (score 0):

```
where inspection_date between to_date('1/1/1800','mm/dd/yyyy') and to_date('1/1/2000','mm/dd/yyyy')
```